# Integrating DoDirect API using php in PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to get the Paypal issue resolved whereby the users are made to make payments using the Do Direct method of Paypal... please suggest me some sort of tutorial for this implementation..

Answer (score 0):

Check the paypal integration center, I think what you're calling "do direct" is the Express checkout process.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout

Comment: no .. can you please suggest me something on the DoDirect method... I guess what I am asking is the API for that.. what I need to implement is the DoDirect method in the web site..

Answer (score 0):

For Direct payment you have to use the NVP api.
Here's an example using Cake PHP and cURL but I think you can port it easily to pure PHP.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/paypal-datasource

Comment: Here's the official paypal docs as well.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview

Answer (score 0):

official paypal docs as SleepyCod pointed out

_https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview#id09C2F060QRO

and

here is a sample code

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_DoDirectPayment_php.txt